# Как получить данные с удалённого хоста

Tags: javascript, django, angular2, cors, cross-domain

Пожалуйста получить данные с удалённого хоста.

По http://localhost:8000/messages/index Django framework возвращает следующий JSON:

```
[
    {'key': val},
    {'key': val},
    {'key': val},
    {'key': val}
]
```

По http://localhost:4200/ angular2 возвращает JSON через service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {

    private messagesArr: any[];

  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.messagesArr = localStorage.messages ? localStorage.messages : [];
  };

  private messages: any[] = [];

  getMessages(): Observable<any> {
    let result = this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/messages/index');
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }   

}
```

Component:

```
.....
  ngOnInit() {
    this.messagesService
        .getMessages()
        .map((response: Response) => JSON.parse(response.json()))
        .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.messages = data;
                  }, 
                  err => {
                    console.log('err')         
                  }); 
  }  
.....
```

В Django я разрешил следующие хосты:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'http://localhost:4200', 'localhost']
```

Разрешил CORS:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

В результате Chrome-browser на вкладке 'network' отображает удачный запрос:
[screenshot](https://i.yapx.ru/PrD3.png), [screenshot](https://i.yapx.ru/PrD4.png)

Но консоль Chrome-browser отображает сообщение об ошибке:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/messages/index. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.
>
> err

Comment: У вас django-cors-headers подключен-то?

Comment: Вы правы. Подключил, заработало.

Comment: Однако, всё равно странно. Как видно из скриншота, JSON поступает в браузер в виде ответа удалённого сервера

Comment: Не странно, эту ошибку в консоли создаёт не сервер, а браузер — полученный ответ просто отбрасывался браузером по соображениям безопасности

Comment: Но, насколько я понимаю, в таких случаях браузер хотя бы ругается на кроссдоменный запрос. И уж никак ответ с кодом 200 не показывает: https://i.yapx.ru/PrD3.png

Comment: Это и есть ошибка кроссдоменного запроса, всё показывает ровно так, как и должно